# PageMethods not calling function from codebehind - undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

I'm building a site to build your own cake. Each cake has a base price, and certain options. Some options (strawberry filling for example) add an additional price to the cake. This price is in the database, found by the feature id.

I'm trying to write a function that will update the price whenever you pick some new option. To select features, I have dropdown boxes and checkboxlists. They display the text of the option, but the value of the option is the feature id. I have a JS function to go through and get the values of each selected item.

My idea is to call additionalPrice whenever a ddl/cbl is changed, which will query the database with the feature ids, and add the extra price. The problem is that PageMethods is undefined. It wont autofill when I'm typing in in VS2012, and is colored black instead of light blue. I've read other problems like this, and I'm pretty sure i'm doing everything right. Here's my code...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
EnablePageMethods="true" 
EnablePartialRendering="true"  runat="server" />

<script>
$('.featureDropDown').change(function (a) {
            //var price = $.ajax({ url: 'ajax/totalproductprice.ashx', async: false }).responseText;
            var price = PageMethods.additionalPrice();
            alert(price);
</script>
```

Codebehind...

```
 [WebMethod] public static int additionalPrice()
    {
        return 77; 
    }
```

additionalPrice will have more logic once I get this to work. With this code, when you change a dropdownlist, it alerts 'undefined'.

EDIT: Now that first question has been solved, I have another one. I am trying to set the label that holds the final price to the value returned from additionalPrice. I'm trying to do this in the onSuccess method in PageMethods. I just have a generic label at the top of the page -

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" />
```

Here is my onSuccess, and the different things I have tried. None of them do anything to the label.

```
function onSuccess(result) {
            alert(result + "worked");
            $('.lblPrice').attr("text", result);
            $('.lblPrice').attr('text', function () {
                $(this).attr('text', result);
            })
            $('.lblPrice').text(result);
            document.getElementById('lblPrice').value = result;
            document.all('lblPrice').innerHTML = result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using ASP.NET AJAX `PageMethods` there's a success and failure callback function that you can subscribe to by passing two additional parameters to the call.  In this case you'll want to use

```
$(function () {
    $('.featureDropDown').change(function (a) {
        //var price = $.ajax({ url: 'ajax/totalproductprice.ashx', async: false }).responseText;
        PageMethods.additionalPrice(onSuccess, onFailure);
    });

    function onSuccess(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function onFailure(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they were required. Also, now it alerts 'undefined', which is price, and then 77, which is onSuccess. It's not setting price to 77. I also have

    `code  $('.lblPrice').attr("src", price);
                    $('.lblPrice').attr('src', function () {
                        $(this).attr('src', price);
                    })`

which isn't changing anything. It's after setting the price variable. This isn't changing the lblPrice at all. I tried moving it to onSuccess, but it also didn't work. Any idea on changing the label to the new price?

Comment: it's alerting `undefined` because you're setting `price` equal to `PageMethods.additionalPrice(onSuccess, onFailure);` which returns `undefined`.  If you want to set price set it in the `onSuccess` function, `var price = result;` you can then put the logic to set the label in the `onSuccess` function as well.

Comment: I moved it ton `onSuccess`, but it still didn't work. This is what I have - `function onSuccess(result) {
                alert(result + "worked");
                $('.lblPrice').attr("text", result);
                $('.lblPrice').attr('text', function () {
                    $(this).attr('text', result);
                })
            }`
Sorry for no line breaks, not sure how. It alerts 77worked, but doesn't change the label.

Comment: I think you want [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/): `$('.lblPrice').text(result)`.

Comment: please edit your question with additional code, what is `.lblPrice`, a span?  what does your markup look like?

Comment: lblPrice is just a label. I added code to the original question.

Comment: you'll need to add `CssClass="lblPrice"` to `<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" />` in order to use `.lblPrice` in your jQuery selector

Comment: First one worked, second one didn't. Thanks a lot for helping out a newb :)

Answer (score 0):

To call web methods from JavaScript make sure you are calling using the `<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) where your web method is located. Also if you decide to add you web method's to a sperate file, which for scalability up might want to do, you will need to add the reference to your script manager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/SomeWebServices.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Yes, and then the as pointed out earlier. If it still give s you problems let me know.

```
$(function () {
    $('.featureDropDown').change(function (a) {
        //var price = $.ajax({ url: 'ajax/totalproductprice.ashx', async: false }).responseText;
        PageMethods.additionalPrice(onSuccess, onFailure);
    });

    function onSuccess(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function onFailure(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```